# c++ lambda in stack memory

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

lambda type local variable pointer has a 0xcc 0xcc 0xcc 0xcc

that is not initialize local variable stats

```
int main()
{
    auto a = []()
    {
       printf("aa");
    };

    a();

    int b = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

in visual studio, watch variable &a in break point show

```
&a  0x0113f8d7 {...}    main::__l2::void <lambda>(void) *

0x0113F8D7  cc cc cc cc  ????
0x0113F8DB  cc cc cc cc  ????
```

otherwise, &b show

```
&b  0x0113f8c8 {0x00000001} int *

0x0113F8C8  01 00 00 00  ....
```

i'm wandering about where or how lambda function is called that not initialized

Comment: lambda is functor, what value should it be initialized? What do you expect for it?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/572/lambdas/1854/what-is-a-lambda-expression)

Comment: in visual c++ debug build, local variable that not assigned filled with 0xcc 0xcc 0xcc 0xcc but in case i assigned a to lambda object but it was filled with 0xcc 0xcc 0xcc 0xcc

Comment: in release mode the compiler will probably optimize the lambda away, keeping the call to `printf` only. this is one of the good things about lambda - they encourage the compiler to optimize them away.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ standard requires the size of a *complete* object to be greater than 0 (an empty base class sub-object can occupy 0 bytes).

That lambda object `a` is stateless (because it captures nothing), but it cannot be of zero size, so its size is 1. The contents of this one byte are not defined, since nothing is stored in there.

Note that the compiler may allocate no storage for it at all, as long as the program cannot observe the difference.

Comment: A quick mention of the "all cc" pattern specific to MSVC debug builds would improve this answer I think?

Comment: @Yakk I am not familiar with MSVC and the author indicated expertise with those byte patterns.

Answer (score 2):

A lambda is not a function pointer. It is a class. This code is equivalent to the following:

```
class a_lambda {
public:

  void operator()()
  {
       printf("aa");
  }
};

a_lambda a;
```

"a_lambda" is an internally-generated unique class name that's manufactured by the compiler.

The class does not contain anything and has no class members, so when you look at `&a`, all you see is uninitialized memory.